# Alternative to Windows's file/folder search

Tags: gratis, search, windows-10

It's needless to say that the Windows search utility can be useless at times. It's extraordinarily slow, does not search within *all* folders, and ignores some files on the disk. I'm looking for an alternative where the application would meet these basic requirements,

- Relatively quick
- Gratis
- Can search in all folders (including hidden folders)
- Use wildcards (*.html) for filenames when performing a search
- Runs on Windows 10

Some features that are not necessary but preferred would be,

- Estimates time remaining until completion when performing a search
- Replaces the search bar within Explorer and/or the start menu
- Does not run a service or process when the application is not being run (only runs when the application has been started by the user)
- Can choose the number of subfolders the search will look into
- Can choose to search on multiple disks
- Can view results based on,

  - Date modified
  - Date created
  - Alphabetical order
  - Size on disk

Comment: Search Note is an impressive way to search content inside your shared documents Why don't you give it a try? Search note is available on github
https://github.com/scorpionit01/SearchNote

Answer (score 8):

I would also would like to add the program I currently use called everything. It again meets my requirements but something to note is that the results are instant. It's easy to use and takes up little disk usage as-well. You can search for both folders and files.

## [Everything Search Engine](http://www.voidtools.com/)

> "Everything" is an administrative tool that locates files and folders
>   by filename instantly for Windows. Unlike Windows search "Everything"
>   initially displays every file and folder on local or removable NTFS
>   volumes on your computer (hence the name "Everything"), and on mapped
>   network drives with ETP server and an everything installation too. You
>   type in a search filter to limit what files and folders are displayed.
>   19 languages supported.
>
> #### How is Everything different from other search engines
>
> - Small installation file.
> - Clean and simple user interface.
> - Quick file indexing.
> - Quick searching.
> - Quick startup.
> - Minimal resource usage.
> - Small database on disk.
> - Real-time updating.
>
> [image: Exerything]

Comment: Also, it does not need to be installed and it supports regular expressions.

Answer (score 6):

An application that I have used in the past is called Agent Ransack. It is a free application and meets most of my requirements. It is very fast at finding results and has many options when searching for files.

## [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack)

> Agent Ransack is a tool for finding files and information on your hard
> drive fast and efficiently. When searching the contents of files Agent
> Ransack also displays the text found. Users can then quickly browse
> the results without having to separately open each file! Agent Ransack
> provides compelling advantages over similar search tools:
>
> - Regular expressions that allow complex rule based searches.
> - Immediate contents results view
> - Various wizards to walk the user through thesearching process.
>
> [image: Agent Ransack UI]

Answer (score 3):

Just use [ultrasearch](https://www.jam-software.com/ultrasearch/), fastest I have seen to date and easiest too.

Now for features that you asked for,

- Relatively quick -> Extremely Quick
- Gratis -> YES
- Can search in all folders (including hidden folders) -> YES (Even system folders)
- Use wildcards (*.html) for filenames when performing a search -> YES
- Runs on Windows 10 -> YES

Optional features,

- Estimates time remaining until completion when performing a search -> Shows a progress bar( But it only takes an instant to complete most searches)
- Replaces the search bar within Explorer and/or the start menu -> NO
- Does not run a service or process when the application is not being run (only runs when the application has been started by the user) -> YES
- Can choose the number of subfolders the search will look into -> Not directly but yes
- Can choose to search on multiple disks -> YES
- Can view results based on, -> YES

  - Date modified
  - Date created
  - Alphabetical order

## [UltraSearch](https://www.jam-software.com/ultrasearch/)

> UltraSearch does not maintain an index which is stored on your
> harddisk, but achieves its speed by working directly on the Master
> File Table (MFT) of the NTFS partitions. UltraSearch even identifies
> NTFS hardlinks.
>
> Simply enter a file name or a pattern like *.exe and see the first
> results while you are still typing. In addition, UltraSearch supports
> regular expressions.
>
> [image: UltraSearch UI]

Comment: Great suggestion, +1 on details!!!

Comment: Thanks, its personally my favorite search software right now :)

Answer (score 1):

I use this Python script https://github.com/mikeputnam/simplepythongrep It takes your search term and walks the directories looking for files containing the term.